# ZF2 language translation using api

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working on zf2 translation.Suggest some solution for Dynamic translation of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use gettext for translation

http://www.masterzendframework.com/internationalisation-2/translate-content-translate-viewhelper/

If you want developed module

check this link https://zfmodules.com/danitome24/zf2-languages